# react-navigation v6 listen to goBack

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am working on a project where I have to upgrade from `"react-navigation": "^4.2.2"` to `"@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",`.

There is some legacy code that looks like it adds listeners for `onGoBack` event:

`onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('EditAccount', { onGoBack: () => this.onRefresh(), })}`, which typescript is complaining about.

The update for the route seems to be `this.props.navigation.navigate({ key: 'EditAccount'});` which works fine, but I cannot figure out how to add a listener for "goBack" in v6. According to [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/#cangoback) , `navigation` has an `addListener` method but that only accepts four events and `goBack` is not one of them.

Anyone know how to add a listener for `goBack`?

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the `beforeRemove` event to achieve this. See: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/preventing-going-back/ (I know you're not trying to prevent going back, but the idea is similar.)

Alternatively, the clean up function of the [`useFocusEffect`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/function-after-focusing-screen#triggering-an-action-with-the-usefocuseffect-hook) hook could work.